# Como poner id a los <tr> generados por el datatable

Tags: javascript, laravel, datatables

Estoy creando mis tablas con la libreria datatable , estoy haciendo que consuma mis api laravel mediante ajax.Estoy planteando ocultar las filas por medio de su id pero nose en que parte del datatable puedo agregar el id de mi registro  a los tr.

```
var table = $('#kt_table').DataTable({
            language: {
                url: 'json/spanish.json'
            },
            responsive: true,
            dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>><'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7 dataTables_pager'lp>>",
            ajax:"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tipo_evaluacion_dt",
            columns: [
                {data: 'id', className: 'kt-align-center'},
                {data: 'tipo_evaluacion_nombre'},
                {data: 'tipo_evaluacion_usuario_modificacion_id'},
                {data: 'updated_at', className: 'kt-align-center'},
                {data: 'tipo_evaluacion_estado_id', className: 'kt-align-center'},
                {data: 'btn', className: 'kt-align-center', responsivePriority: -1},
            ],});
```

Comment: podrías poner tu código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes implementar `fnCreatedRow` para obtener cada fila TR (`rowEl`) y luego usar la `data` de la fila para establecer el id (en el ejemplo usé `data[0]` pero deberias usar el indice adecuado correspondiente a la columna `id`).

```
var table = $('#kt_table').DataTable({
  ...
  fnCreatedRow: function( rowEl, data) {
    $(rowEl).attr('id', data[0]);
  }
  ...
}
```

De la misma manera puedes usar `rowEl` de la manera que desees para agregar otros atributos, clases css, etc.

https://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks

**Nota:** esto tambien aplica para cuando se crean filas dinamicamente con Datatable.row.add()(https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add())

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso lo hago diferente: en el JSON que devuelve el servidor agrego por cada fila una entrada bajo la clave 'DT_RowId'=>$idDelRegistro. y listo, el propio DataTables se encarga de establecer el atributo.